# How to pass @input to components

Tags: angular

I have component

```
<app-first param1='param1' param2="param2"></app-first>
```

There is a second in the first component.

```
<app-second title='????'></app-second>
```

How to pass a parameter

```
<app-second title='{{ param1 }}'></app-second>
```

Something like that doesn't work

In the ts file I have

```
@Input() param1 : string;
@Input() param2 : string;
```

Please help me

Comment: Not sure I follow, but use brackets instead `[title]='param1'`

Comment: `@Input() title` needs to be in your `app-second.component.ts` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use binding syntax

```
<app-second [title]='param1'></app-second>
```

Comment: Also looks like he doesn't have `@Input() title` or `@Input('title') param1`

Comment: He shown 2 componens, I assume that was the first one - but that might be wrong.

Comment: He isn't really giving enough information of where and what the vars are.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the double braces. Also the convention is to wrap the input property in brackets to signal it's an input. Output's are wrapped in parenthesis.

<app-second [title]='param1'>